# Permutations - arranging people in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

In how many ways can you arrange 20 boys and 10 girls in 2 circles in this way:

```
Inside the inner circle sits all the girls,
In the outer circle sits all the boys, while Josh sits closest to the door
```

I first thought of it of a regular combinatorics problem, and solved it like this:

The position of josh is irrelevant for the counting since he is static, so we'll count only 19 boys:

There are: $(19-1)!=18!$ ways to arrange 19 boys in a circle, and for every configuration, there are $(10-1)!=9!$ to arrange 10 girls in a circle, so in total it's:

$$18!\cdot9!$$

But I find it hard to understand why I should take the (NumberOfBoys-1)! to calculate the number of combinations so I'm not quite sure I'm right.

Can someone please explain this concept and tell me whether I was right?

Thanks

Comment: Does it matter how the girls are arranged in relation to the boys?  For example if every girl moves one position to the right, is this a different arrangement?

Answer (score 1):

For circular permutation of $n$ objects, we use $(n-1)!$ since we arbitrarily fix one object and then arrange the other objects and the arrangement remains the same irrespective of whom we fix due to circular symmetry.

In your problem, Josh's position is already fixed. So we no longer need to fix any other boy and no. of permutation becomes $19!$. Since the 2 circles together form the arrangement, the girls can be arranged in $10!$ ways since the position of Josh here also serves as the fixed object.

The answer hence should be $19!\cdot 10!$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey aniket can you explain me for $10!$ i am thinking somewhat diffeerent

Comment: @ArchisWelankar We are arranging the girls in a circle. So we should fix one girl as a reference point as I have stated in my answer. But here the 2 concentric circles together form the arrangement. Hence try to imagine this.. the position of Josh itself acts as a reference point. So no need to have one more reference point. Hence $10!$

Comment: ahh. okay thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We subtract $1$ for seating in a circle because $1$ person is "lost" to create a reference point.

Here Josh in fact is automatically a reference point, so arrangements for boys would be $19!$

You were right to doubt the correctness of $18!$

Re girls, you need to clarify the query of Michael Burr. I would *think* that their relation w.r.t Josh matters, so their arrangements would be $10!$

Answer (score 0):

There are $10!$ ways to arrange $10$ girls in a straight line. But when you close the line into a circle (that is forget which of the girls is the first, just remember who is next to whom) it turns out that **each** of such *circle permutations* has been counted $10$ times when we counted "*line permutations*". Therefore there are $10!/10 = (10-1)!$ ways of creating a circle out of $10$ girls.

You can convince yourself of that on a smaller example: take 3 boys: A, B, C.

Line arrangements: ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA. But when you "close the circle", suddenly ABC, CAB, BCA become the same and ACB, CBA, BAC become the same.

When it comes to the boys, and Josh is in a fixed position, I think there are $19!$ ways of positioning other boys, when Josh is a point of reference, so shouldn't the answer be $9!\cdot 19!$ ?

Comment: I would treat Josh as a reference point for the girls as well.